# ASP.Net and Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, collections, n-tier-architecture

I want to build an N-Tier web-application , for shopping cart. I want to follow the concepts collections. That is retrieve data from db, fill it in collections and bind collections with asp.web and html controls.

Or simply i can say , i want to know how to use collections with ASP.Net controls
or 
Some good tutorials or links to learns ASP.Net MVC as I think both are same. Please provide link other than WWW.ASP.NET or any ebooks for the same

Comment: "You guys"? You don't want help from women?

Comment: Guys plural can reference a group of people gender indiscriminately the same way men does when used such as policemen, salesmen, good will to men etc.

Comment: @Chris: if that's true, then it's a new usage. Have a reference for that? You (plural) has the same meaning, which suggests that the addition of "guys" is meant to narrow down the "you".

Comment: @John- Sorry , I did'nt meant that. I have no problem taking help from either men or women. "You guy's" was in my mind and i wrote it. Sorry, again, if it hurts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. I'd suggest you have a look at some of the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/learn/ and then post more specific questions.

Update:

For more information about collections and data binding, have a look at the [data access tutorials](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/) on http://asp.net. Additionally, you can find some good tutorials about data binding and data-bound controls on https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com, e.g [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061709-1.aspx).